# Error NDK Android Javac: error: Class names, are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested

Tags: java, android

I am learning Opencv for android and according to a tutorial I was watching I had to set up JNI.
I have already configured java and ndk to be accesible from the command line (windows) from everywhere.

I have to execute this command in the terminal of android studio:

> javah -d jni -classpath ../../build/intermediates/classes/debug bruno.volcovinsky.aprendiendoopencv.NativeClass

I know that javah is not more useful, so I use instead javac. It gives the same error. I Also tried using `javac -h` (that I saw in some websited)

The video where I saw this is the following: https://youtu.be/mF9fYdXfSD8?t=4m28s

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong?